# Dynamic images in ASP.NET Web application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, svg

Currently i'm investigating the possibilities to show dynamic images in our ASP.NET webforms application.
For example. we want to show the end user a 7 segment display on a web page, but before showing it, we need to change some things in this image, according to some settings in the databse, for example changing colors or set visibility of the segments, change background colors of elements etc.

Since our end users do not have the ablity to install browser plugins like Flash or Silverlight, it has to be something that is native supported by all recent browsers (maybe something like HTML5 or SVG?).

The main images should be created in design-time with some sort of WYSIWYG editor, like Illustrator or Blend or something. In run-time, we need to manipulate the image from C# (if serverside), or maybe even javascript (if clientside).

The main question is, are there eny techniques you would recommend, or are there any existing frameworks or libraries to accomplish this? Can this be easily done with SVG or HTML5 (canvas?)

I hope anyone can point me in the right direction, or provide some tips or maybe a good tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

When I had to do something like this I used a new HTTP Handler. There in ProcesRequest you can load the image in a Bitmap object and modify it in-memory. After you are done you can write the image to the response.

```
    //load the main image
    var bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200);

    //draw here

    bmp.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";

    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

After having a handler like this you can add  to the HTML. Make sure the response is not cached so the images are really dynamic.

Storing and editing the main image is a different question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i was more looking for something where the actual image contains elements (like SVG or XAML), where i can manipulate the properties of those elements (like positioning, colors, visibility)